# getting a tab name instead of the index

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have an application that updates databases based on the tabs name been clicked on. I need to be able to get the tab's name using the index number.

```
<div id="id_tabs" class="tabs" > </div>
<ul class="d_tabs">
  <li id="id_tab_home"><a href="#tab_home">Home</div>     </a></li>
  <li id="id_tab_first"><a href="#tab_first">First</div></a></li>
  <li id="id_tab_second"><a href="#tab_second">Second</div></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I assume you're using jQuery UI's tabs?  Also, what qualifies as the tab's "Name"?

Comment: your html is malformed... you have closing div tags where there's no div

Answer (score 3):

`$('ul.d_tabs li').eq(idx).attr("id")` will return the ID (string) for whatever `idx` (number) you feed it.

Comment: and `.split("id_tab_")[1]` will get you the raw name.

Comment: just a heads up `eq` is `0` based so you might want to do `eq(idx-1)`

Comment: Both good points, thanks. Obviously it all depends on what OP actually meant by 'name' and 'index number'.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your HTML code is not valid, `</div>` is closed before `</a>` fix that

code for getting name is like this in click method

```
var name = $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + ' a:first-child').html();
```

and that is it